# Issues with Infrared Receiver on Raspberry Pi 4B: Unexpected Signals and Empty Raw Code Configuration

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, remote-control

**Issue 1:**
When running the command "mode2 --driver default --device /dev/lirc1" on my Raspberry Pi 4B, with an infrared receiver connected to GPIO18, i am observing that the command outputs signals even when no signals are being sent to the receiver. The output looks something like this:

```bash
root@raspberrypi:~# mode2 --driver default --device /dev/lirc1
Using driver default on device /dev/lirc1
Trying device: /dev/lirc1
Using device: /dev/lirc1
Warning: Running as root.
pulse 891
space 624
pulse 164
space 1775
pulse 979
space 13428
pulse 318
space 19594
pulse 1747
timeout 129678
pulse 138
space 3257
pulse 793
space 15736
pulse 2111
timeout 129148
```

**Issue 2:**
When running the command "irrecord -f -d /dev/lirc1 --disable-namespace" to record the infrared signals from your remote control, i am getting an empty raw_code configuration. The output of the command looks like this:

```bash
begin remote

  name  uu
  driver devinput
  bits           64
  eps            30
  aeps          100

  one             0     0
  zero            0     0
  gap          43938
  toggle_bit_mask 0x0
  frequency    38000

      begin codes
      end codes

end remote
```

**something about my pi4**

```bash
root@raspberrypi:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

```bash
root@raspberrypi:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=18
dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=17
```

```bash
root@raspberrypi:~/.cache# cat irrecord.log 
Oct  3 15:24:25.026229 raspberrypi irrecord: Warning: ------------------------ Log re-opened ----------------------------
Oct  3 15:24:25.026516 raspberrypi irrecord: Info: irrecord:  Opening log, level: Info
Oct  3 15:24:25.026770 raspberrypi irrecord: Info: Initial device: /dev/lirc1
Oct  3 15:24:25.026849 raspberrypi irrecord: Info: initializing '/dev/lirc1'
Oct  3 15:24:25.026916 raspberrypi irrecord: Info: Using device: /dev/lirc1
Oct  3 15:24:25.027035 raspberrypi irrecord: Warning: can't get exclusive access to events coming from `/dev/lirc1' interface
Oct  3 15:24:34.007855 raspberrypi irrecord: Error: error reading '/dev/lirc1'
Oct  3 15:24:34.119868 raspberrypi irrecord: Error: error reading '/dev/lirc1'
Oct  3 15:24:34.139849 raspberrypi irrecord: Error: error reading '/dev/lirc1'
Oct  3 15:24:34.251848 raspberrypi irrecord: Error: error reading '/dev/lirc1'
Oct  3 15:24:35.275909 raspberrypi irrecord: Error: error reading '/dev/lirc1'
Oct  3 15:24:35.296003 raspberrypi irrecord: Error: error reading '/dev/lirc1'
Oct  3 15:24:35.316018 raspberrypi irrecord: Error: error reading '/dev/lirc1'
Oct  3 15:24:35.335886 raspberrypi irrecord: Error: error reading '/dev/lirc1'
Oct  3 15:24:35.380035 raspberrypi irrecord: Error: error reading '/dev/lirc1'
```

i want to solve the problem which the pi4 recv the empty raw code